# The land, the ocean, the sky & our home in one word

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

> My prefix is in the sky.
> My suffix is in the ocean.
> My infix is on land.
> My whole is our home.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The word you seek is:

> **PLANET**

*My prefix is in the sky.*

> Look up *in the sky* and you might spot a **PLANE** flying overhead...

*My suffix is in the ocean.*

> Cast your **NET** *in the ocean* to try and catch a fish!

*My infix is on land.*

> A country **LANE** (or a LANE on a motorway) will help you get places *on land*.

*My whole is our home.*

> All in all, for every one of us, this **PLANET** is *our home*!

Answer (score 1):

A different but similar solution

The word you seek is

> PLANET EARTH

My prefix is in the sky.

> a PLANE is in the sky

My suffix is in the ocean.

> TEARTH are in the ocean (alternative way of writing TEARS)

My infix is on land.

> a LANE is on the ground

My whole is our home.

> PLANET EARTH

Comment: Downvoted because there is nothing new in this particular answer, and shows an attempt of Plagiarism.

Comment: i came up with this answer on my own, but read the other answer before posting. I think my answer is more fitting as "our home" as the other answer is more "generic"

Comment: The suffix is a bit wild. That word is not in Lexico dictionary, nor in the ocean.

Comment: Not to mention the title indicates the answer is ONE word